# targeting iframe in another frame works locally but not remotely

Tags: html, iframe

I am having a weird problem I don't know how to trouble shoot because locally it works fine but when I upload it to my server it does not.

I have an index.html file with two iframes:

```
<iframe seamless frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="auto" name="top" id="top" src="venues.php" width="100%" height="100" />
</iframe>
<iframe seamless frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="auto" name="main" id="main" src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="2000" />
</iframe>
```

In the top iframe I have some links with target="main" which open in the "main" iframe.

When I click on these links in my local environment it works as expected but when I upload the same files and I click on those links the links open in the full window (replacing the index.html file that has the iframes code)

How is this possible?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The server could be configured to not allow loading of content within frames by utilizing the `X-Frame-Options` header. Check the response in Chrome Dev Tools and see if that header is displayed and set to `DENY`.

Comment: @J.Titus wow weird, did know about that... I just read about X-Frame-Options and I tried to include <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny"> in my index.html but Chrome Dev Tools says "X-Frame-Options may only be set via an HTTP header sent along with a document. It may not be set inside <meta>." Also I don't see anything else about X-Frame-Options in Chrome Dev Tools because by the time I click on a link it opens a new page... how can I set this X-Frame-Options to ALLOW from the HTML document? Can do it in HTML or can it only be done via server?

Comment: It can only be set via the server. In Dev Tools click the `Preserve Log` check box so the network activity doesn't go away when the page changes.

Comment: @J.Titus thanks. I click on Preserve Log and I only see two instances of "Navigated to ..." - do you know how I can set it via server if I have CPanel access?

Comment: If you have access to `.htaccess` you could try adding this line: `Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "SAMEORIGIN"` (or `"NONE"` if you want to shut it off completely, which is not suggested for security reasons). Otherwise, I'm not sure.